# Why do I get this error when setting up a Flutter Firebase method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Please help! I am following this tutorial about how to set up an auth method with Firebase.
https://github.com/RobertBrunhage/flutter_firebase_auth_tutorial

Everything is fine except one thing that appears when I run my code at the end:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_application_1/main.dart' as entrypoint;
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/generated_plugin_registrant.dart';

typedef _UnaryFunction = dynamic Function(List<String> args);
typedef _NullaryFunction = dynamic Function();
Future<void> main() async {
  registerPlugins(webPluginRegistrar);
  await ui.webOnlyInitializePlatform();          //IN THIS LINE THE ERROR
  if (entrypoint.main is _UnaryFunction) {
    return (entrypoint.main as _UnaryFunction)(<String>[]);
  }
  return (entrypoint.main as _NullaryFunction)();
}
```

It says that:

> The function 'webOnlyInitializePlatform' isn't defined.
>
> Try importing the library that defines 'webOnlyInitializePlatform', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'webOnlyInitializePlatform'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tutorial followed is old and flutter back then didn't have proper web support it was in beta
The official Flutter Github has a migration [guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-from-package:flutter_web-to-the-Flutter-SDK#clean-up-the-web-directory) which may help you

You can also check the open issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44145)

Comment: Did you ever learn how to resolve this issue?  I am running into a similar issue, but only when I launch the app from Chrome.

Comment: The migration seems to fix it